# xterm not wrapping text properly

Tags: linux, bash, debian, xterm, bashrc

I'm configuring both my gnome-terminal and xterm columns (i still haven't picked which of these I will be using) and I have a couple of issues I would like to fix:

- the typing area seems to be smaller (fewer columns) than the display area
- the typed text is not wrapping to the next line when it reaches the end - it just continues back around on the same line, overwriting the prompt

(i have set a custom bash prompt with PS1 in case this is relevant)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
Release:    7.1
Codename:   wheezy
$ echo $TERM
xterm
$ stty -a
[peter@mine ~] $ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 52; columns 126; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
$[peter@mine ~] $ # the column width only goes up to here ------------------------------------------------>
```

the results are identical in both the xterm and in gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1

and as you can see, the output of the `stty -a` command goes right up to the edge of the screen, while the typing does not go that far.

I have found that I can get the desired result by setting the columns to a very large number, eg:

```
$ stty cols 1800
```

this fixes both problems. Is it the right way to go about solving this problem? Will this "break" any of the output from programs? So far I have tried `top` and `stty -a` and these seem OK.

**more info as requested in the comments**

i found that if i `cat` some input into a file then the columns actually strech the full width of the terminal window:

```
[peter@mine applications] $ cat > /tmp/asd
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqq
```

does this imply that it is actually bash that is restricting the number of columns and not the terminal? if so then how to alter the number of columns in bash?

Comment: Please always mention your operating system. xterm runs on Linux, Unix, BSD, OSX, Solaris, etc etc. Also, are you actually using the `xterm` terminal emulator? `$TERM` does not define the emulator being run, only its type.

Comment: ok i have added that info.

Comment: So, is this actually `xterm` or another terminal emulator? Also, try removing your custom PS1, do you still have this issue?

Comment: And do you have the same problems if you’re typing into something other than `bash`; e.g., `csh` or `cat` (type `cat > /tmp/asdfg`; end with Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D)?

Comment: thanks for the diagnosis suggestions. i will post the results when i get back home later on today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely you don't have properly escaped ANSI code in your prompt definition in your `~/.bashrc`

For instance, a `PS1` something like:

```
    PS1='\033[1;33m>\033[0m '
```

... Will wrap badly, before the width of the shell itself.

Placing square brackets before the ascii escape character and after the definition terminator will fix this, resulting in expected wrapping:

```
    PS1='\[\033[1;33m\]>\[\033[0m\] '
```

I.e `\033` becomes `\[\033` and `m` becomes `m\]`

(I learned this myself some time ago [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO)).

Comment: excellent! that worked! i used `\e` instead of '\033' since both of these are the ascii escape sequence.

Comment: Here are two links that are extremely useful: http://askubuntu.com/a/24422/334235 and http://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/  It makes escaping the square brackets much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out in the comments, your question--even after "clarifying"--is unclear and "incomplete". For instance, you are still not saying whether you're **referring to *xterm* the Program/Application/Terminal-emulator or the *type* of terminal** (i.e. the value you get when you type $TERM. Regardless, I'll attempt provide an answer--or at least to guide you in the right direction.

Given the fact that you customized your bash prompt, I'm assuming this will be the root of your problem.  There's a [number of pertinent discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133031/shell-prompt-line-wrapping-issue), references, information on the frequent line-wrap problems users run into after customizing bash. This appears to be, in most cases, an issue with [*escaping ANSI color codes*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053); some more [Q&A's on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+prompt).

Again, I'm not sure *how* you did the customization (that `stty` output doesn't tell me anything), since there a few number of options to achieve this; however, if you did a **backup** of your *default settings* and *files*, that should be your first line of action.  Alternatively, you could also try `shopt -s checkwinsize` to make sure it's selected, or just `shopt -p` will give you the listing of the bash options that are either **-s**:*selected* or **-u**:*unselected*. Also, check your manual pages to get an idea about some of these things, especially if it's your login shell.

Finally, try to be a little more specific when asking questions; or even better, do a search before for similar questions that might have been already asked.