# xterm text wrapping and reverse command search not working properly

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, arch-linux, xterm

My set up is: `Arch Linux, i3, xterm.` I would be happy to provide other details as well.

I have been facing this problem for quite sometime now. Here it is.
When there is certain text on the window and after resizing the terminal, the text does not wrap around according to the dimensions of the terminal. The following screenshots should make this clear.

Screenshot when the terminal is at it's initial dimensions:

[image: screenshot when the terminal is at it's initial dimensions]

Sreenshot when a new terminal is opened (have a look at the text in the left terminal):

[image: screenshot when a new terminal is opened (have a look at the text in the left terminal)]

When the latter terminal is killed, have a look at the text in the former terminal:

[image: when the latter terminal is killed, have a look at the text in the former terminal]

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/652330/xterm-not-wrapping-text-properly) it has got something to do with `PS1` but that doesn't help either. My `PS1` as set in `.bashrc` is:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;35m\][\u:\w]\$\[\e[0;35m\] '
```

Ideally I want the text re-wrap to fit the dimensions rather than disappearing altogether.

The second problem I am facing has to do with reversing command search using `up arrow key.`. After pressing `up arrow key` for certain times, the text of previous commands stays.

eg: certain of my previous commands are (first one is the latest command);

```
$ echo $PS1
$ cd
$ mv 2021-02-04-094047_1910x422_scrot.png ~
$ scrot -s
$ ls
```

but when I do press the `up arrow key`, following happens;

```
$ echo $PS1
$ cd
$ mv 2021-02-04-094047_1910x422_scrot.png ~
$ mv 2021scrot -s
```

See the persistance of `mv20201` in the last command (which should have been `scrot -s` only.

I would really appreciate your help on this. Happy to provide any other information needed.

**Edit 1**: Even after setting `PS1` to random values (eg: `export PS1='>'`, the problem persists. So I can only speculate `PS1` has got nothing to do with what I am facing.

Comment: OK. I can see you fixed what my answer talks about. You say the problem persists. Did you test by spawning terminals and shells *anew*?

Comment: Yes. I repeated all the steps. And the results from the screenshots remain the same.

Comment: Yes, the problem persists.